# How to Copy Paste Userform Controls to a Worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba, controls, userform, worksheet

Please, can someone help me!

I have a userform which is called Configurator or "Config", which has some Image-Controls.
These images together look like a door, because the userform is a configurator for doors.
(where you can change width, height, material etc...)
Mostly the "door" consists of 4 different images which make the doorframe.

Now i want to use these images on my excel-worksheet, so the user sees a picture of the door on
the worksheet too.

Which method is the best way?
I tried to copy & paste the images from userform to a excel worksheet, but i dont know how.
I hope someone of you can show me the right way to do this!

Another way could be to somehow make a screenshot of a specific area of the userform
and paste the image to the worksheet. I dont know if there is a way to do this?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You cannot copy it, but try inserting an `Image` control and place on it the necessary picture...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, try the next way:

Let us say that `pictDoor1` is the name of the picture you need to 'copy' and a new button to copy it (`copyPicture`). Copy next code in its `Click` event:

```
Private Sub copyPicture_Click()
   Dim shPict As MSForms.Image, pic As MSForms.Image
   Set pic = Me.pictDoor1 'use here the real name of the Image control
   Set shPict = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.Image.1", link:=False, _
        DisplayAsIcon:=False, left:=20, top:=20, width:=pic.width, height:=pic.height).Object
   shPict.Picture = pic.Picture
End Sub
```

It will insert an `Image` control (as the picture to be copied dimensions, cut you can change them by multiplying, if need bigger ones) and place on it the necessary picture.

Then, use the newly created shape `top` and `left` according to the previously created `width` and `height` to appropriately position them...

Comment: @keyv108 Didn't you find some time to test the above suggestion? If tested, didn't it solve your problem? Is it something you do not understand? If so, please do not hesitate to ask for clarifications...

Comment: the answer above helped me solve the problem - thanks!